# use subprocess.Popen with an interactive program

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have a program that when I run in shell, it asks for input from the user.
When I run it as follows with `subprocess.Popen`, it does not get into the part of the program
where it asks for input and it just finishes. How could I change that?

```
cmd = ["./pairwise", "-seq", sites, "-loc", locs, "-lk", "species_genotypenew_lk.txt", "-prefix", ldhat_out]
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if `pairwise` is reads from stdin and writes to stdout

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate()
```

should do it.

Comment: Works great, thanks!